# Repeatedly calling gcm.register(SENDER_ID)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am aware of Google new Docs, it suggests to call GCM register only once in the startup and store the ID. After publishing the app on play store some IDs are going "error":"NotRegistered", App version didnt upgraded, users stop getting notifications.

Reading online solutions to this problem, some suggested to call register function again/repeatedly.

so i Implemented this code

```
regid="";
while (regid.isEmpty())
{
regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
}

String storeid = getRegistrationId(context);

if (!regid.equals(storeid)) 
{

//storing to server
sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

// storing in shared preference
storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
}
```

PS: This is not actual full code, but this is to give basic Idea. getRegistrationId gives Null, if App version changes.

Im calling register function every time, it may give same duplicate value, then comparing and if necessary storing procedure starts.

Now the question

1. Is it okay to call register function every time ? (knowing the duplicate result)
2. By calling register function repeatedly, will it refreshes device activity/status on GCM server side ?
3. Why some devices getting "error":"NotRegistered" errors (didn't uninstalled app), will this implementation has any good ?

All devices are Android 4 and Up.

Developers with experience in GCM, please suggest

Comment: Do the devices that get `NotRegistered` ever get the notifications? (before they start getting the `NotRegistered` error of course). You should investigate why you get these `NotRegistered` errors instead of coding work-arounds.

Comment: Yes, they used to get notifications, recently getting errors one by one, NotRegistered number increasing slowly